# gmaps is not showing the map if gmaps.figure() is not the last line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

In this program I'm creating a chatbot which will respond with the coordinates of some location I'll ask and then these coordinates are passed to

```
gmaps.figure()
```

The program works fine if

```
gmaps.figure(center=coordinates, zoom_level=zoom)
```

is the last line of the code. But if I include this line under the if body then the code doesn't display any error but the map is also not visible.

The commented part of the code is where I'm not able to see the map.

This simple example works.

```py
import gmaps
gmaps.configure(api_key=my_key)
print(type(30.2690717))
new_york_coordinates = (30.2690717, 77.9910673)
gmaps.figure(center=new_york_coordinates, zoom_level=17)
```

This works but when the last line of the code is deleted and the commented statement under if is uncommented map is not shown.

```py
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import os
import gmaps

bot = ChatBot("Bot")
trainer = ListTrainer(bot)
cor = []
for files in os.listdir("C://Users/Administrator/Desktop/Internship Project/chatterbot-corpus-master/chatterbot_corpus/data/english"):
    data = open("C://Users/Administrator/Desktop/Internship Project/chatterbot-corpus-master/chatterbot_corpus/data/english/"+files,'r').readlines()
    trainer.train(data)
gmaps.configure(api_key=my_key)


message = input('You:')
if(message.strip() != 'Bye'):
    reply = bot.get_response(message)
    cor = reply.text.split(',')
    lat = (float)(cor[0].strip('-'))
    lon = (float)(cor[1])
    zoom = (float)(cor[2])
    coordinates = (lat, lon)
    #gmaps.figure(center=coordinates, zoom_level=zoom)
gmaps.figure(center=coordinates, zoom_level=zoom)
```

I expect to see the map figure even if `gmaps.figure()` is not the last line of the code.

But when `gmaps.figure()` is not the last line of the code there is no error but the map is also not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gmaps.figure()` returns a `Widget` and that's why you are facing this.
In order to render a widget at any given time(any line in your case), simply use `IPython`'s `display` function.

```py
import gmaps
from IPython.display import display

#...
# suppose you have multiple figures to show, here is one
fig1 = gmaps.figure(..)
# simply use display to render the figure
display(fig1)

# ... 
# and here's a second one after more lines of code
# and it no more needs to be the last line of code!
fig2 = gmaps.figure(..)
display(fig2)

# random code etc
```

This allows you to render any widgets any time you like. You no more have to display your figure at the last line of code in a notebook cell to have it displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `print()` inside the `if` statement. If your `gmaps.figure` is inside the `if`, it will be triggered when `(message.strip() != 'Bye')==TRUE` . So the problem is what happens with the `if` statement. When you put it in the last line it's outside the `if`. Python is a **space sensitive language**.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Thanasis Saxanidis but this doesn't seem to be working for me. I tried adding print() inside the if statement. The output is still not what I expect.

Comment: what i meant before is toy use print("debug"), for example inside the "if". If it does not printed then there is problem with your if statement. From what you describe there is no problem with gmaps.figure . It does not matter if it's the last line of code

Comment: `import gmaps gmaps.configure(api_key=my_key) new_york_coordinates = (30.2690717, 77.9910673) gmaps.figure(center=new_york_coordinates, zoom_level=17) print("Hi")
`
even in this case it doesn't works because gmaps.figure() is not the last line.